# Makefile Error: No such file or directory, no input files

Tags: c, makefile

I'm having some issues with the makefile I made:

```
CC=gcc                         # Compiler variable
CFLAGS=-Wall -m32    # Options passed to the compiler
DEPS =

# Generic Rule for .o files
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

program: source1.o
    $(CC) -o program source1.o

#program: source1.o source2.o
#   $(CC) -o source1.o source2.o

source1.o: source1.c
    $(CC)  -o source1 source1.c $(CFLAGS) 

#source2.o: source2.c
#   $(CC) -o source2 source2.c $(CFLAGS)
```

I changed my file names to things like "source1" and "program" for generalization purposes.
Right now I'm trying to get the makefile work with one source code. I hope to add more source code down the line, which I will implement via the commented out code.

This is what happens when I run "make" in the terminal:

```
[terminal] (2)$ make
gcc                 -o source1 source1.c -Wall -m32     
gcc                -o program source1.o
gcc: source1.o: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I don't know why I'm getting an error, does anyone have any ideas on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
source1.o: source1.c
        $(CC) -o source1 source1.c $(CFLAGS)
```

You have specified the output file as `source1` when you meant `source1.o`.  This should be:

```
source1.o: source1.c
        $(CC) -c -o source1.o source1.c $(CFLAGS)
```

You can use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) like `$@` (for the target) and `$<` (for the first prerequisite) to avoid silly typos like that.

Comment: Oh you're also missing the `-c` flag; if you want to build an object file, not an executable, you have to add that.

Comment: I added -c to my flags variable, and added source1.o instead of source1, and I get the following error: 

/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `source1.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: error in cache1D.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
/usr/bin/ld: program: Unable to sort relocs - they are of an unknown size
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program] Error 1

Comment: If you're going to compile your object files as 32bit (the `-m32` flag) then you better also link it as 32bit (pass that flag to the linker as well).